# A reliable script to convert Tiki-Wiki tables to MediaWiki format?

Tags: mediawiki, tiki-wiki

I know I can copy the rendered Tiki-Wiki page into LibreOffice and then export it into MediaWiki format, but what about hundreds of pages? Is there a reliable script?

I need to convert only tables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert this:

```
||row1-column1|row1-column2||row2-column1|row2-column2||
```

Into this:

```
{|
| row1-column1||row1-column2
|-
| row2-column1||row2-column2
|}
```

So your script has to do 5 string substitutions:

1. Replace the first `||` by `{|\n`
2. Replace the last `||` by `\n|}`
3. Replace every other `||` by `@@SEPARATOR_ROW@@`
4. Replace every `|` by `||`
5. Replace every `@@SEPARATOR_ROW@@` by `\n|-\n`

Another way could be to convert your tiki table in HTML format, as MediaWiki also supports HTML  format.

References for the wiki syntax:

- http://doc.tiki.org/Wiki-Syntax+Tables?structure=HomePage+UserGuide
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables